# Infinite dimensional finitely generated algebraic division algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, division-algebras, division-rings

> Is there a division algebra $D$ with center $K$ that satisfies the
>   following 3 conditions?

1) $D$ is of infinite dimension over $K$;

2) every element of $D$ is algebraic over $K$;

3) $D$ is finitely generated (as division $K$-algebra).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a fairly well known old and open (as far as I know) problem: Kurosh’s Problem for division rings. See, for example, Question 3 in Agata Smoktunovicz’s [2006 ICM talk](http://icm2006.org/proceedings/Vol_II/contents/ICM_Vol_2_12.pdf).